# Owl Carousel Duplicate Slider - External XML driven

Tags: jquery, asp.net, xml, owl-carousel

//////////

Update - the issues was on line 81

Dim nodes2 As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc2.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/xml/books/book")

I wasn't using xmlDoc2 after the = sign.

//////////

I keep getting a duplicate owl carousel when trying to read in XML for an external source. I want to see 2 different carousels.

I made sure we have different IDs and that we are calling them. The XML is valid on both and while the schema is different, we are just looping through the materials. I've also tried 2 different versions of jquery 2.0 and 1.12 from the big G.

If I replace the first XML string mURL with mURL2 it does show the replaced list twice which means to me I am overwriting my value somehow.

Example: http://images2.toledolibrary.org/imagewall/_new/2016%20-%20OPAC/opac.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<%@ Import Namespace=System.Web.UI  %>
<%@ Import Namespace=System.Xml  %>
<%@ Import Namespace=System.IO  %>
<!DOCTYPE html>


<script runat="server">

Sub Page_Load()
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

        Dim mURL As String
        Dim mURL2 As String


mURL = "http://bookdb.nextgoodbook.com/v3/api/booklist/lid/43604001/nlid/23581/format/xml"


        Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()

        xmlDoc.Load(mURL)

        Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/xml/books/book")



        Dim pId As String = ""
        Dim pIsbn As String = ""
        Dim pTitle As String = ""
        Dim pAuthor As String = ""
        Dim pTitleCk As String = ""
        Dim intCount As Integer = 0


        ltlBooks.Text = ltlBooks.Text & ("<div id=owl-carousel class=owl-carousel owl-theme>")



        For Each node As XmlNode In nodes

            pId = node.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText
            pIsbn = node.SelectSingleNode("isbn").InnerText
            pTitle = node.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText
            pAuthor = node.SelectSingleNode("author").InnerText


            If (pTitle = pTitleCk) Then
            Else


         <%--      Response.Write(pId & "<br>" & pIsbn & "<br>" & pTitle & "<br>" & pAuthor & "<br><br>") --%>

                ltlBooks.Text = ltlBooks.Text & ("<div class=item><a href=http://bookdb.nextgoodbook.com/borrow/at/cd43303c6a75acf5b2e4e739a060de31/" & pIsbn & ">" & "<img width=100% src=http://contentcafe2.btol.com/ContentCafe/Jacket.aspx?UserID=TOL67950&Password=CC11779&Return=1&Type=L&Value=" & pIsbn & " /></a></div>")

                intCount = intCount + 1

            End If

            pTitleCk = pTitle

        Next

        ltlBooks.Text = ltlBooks.Text & ("</div>")



        <%-- ----------------- --%>





mURL2 = "http://bookdb.nextgoodbook.com/v3/api/custom/lid/43604001/nlid/16461/format/xml"

<%-- kids           

mURL2 = "http://bookdb.nextgoodbook.com/v3/api/custom/lid/43604001/nlid/26575/format/xml"
    --%>

        Dim xmlDoc2 As New XmlDocument()
        xmlDoc2.Load(mURL2)


        Dim nodes2 As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/xml/books/book")



        Dim pId2 As String = ""
        Dim pIsbn2 As String = ""
        Dim pTitle2 As String = ""
        Dim pAuthor2 As String = ""
        Dim pTitleCk2 As String = ""
        Dim intCount2 As Integer = 0


        ltlBooks2.Text = ltlBooks2.Text & ("<div id=owl-carousel2 class=owl-carousel2 owl-theme>")



        For Each dvdnode As XmlNode In nodes2

            pId2 = dvdnode.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText
            pIsbn2 = dvdnode.SelectSingleNode("isbn").InnerText
            pTitle2 = dvdnode.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText
            pAuthor2 = dvdnode.SelectSingleNode("author").InnerText


            If (pTitle2 = pTitleCk2) Then
            Else



                ltlBooks2.Text = ltlBooks2.Text & ("<div class=item><a href=http://bookdb.nextgoodbook.com/borrow/at/cd43303c6a75acf5b2e4e739a060de31/" & pIsbn2 & ">" & "<img width=100% src=http://contentcafe2.btol.com/ContentCafe/Jacket.aspx?UserID=TOL67950&Password=CC11779&Return=1&Type=L&Value=" & pIsbn2 & " /></a></div>")

                intCount2 = intCount2 + 1

            End If

            pTitleCk2 = pTitle2

        Next

        ltlBooks2.Text = ltlBooks2.Text & ("</div>")






    End If
End Sub

</script>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">

<title>DVD Carousel</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">


<!-- Important Owl stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl.carousel.css">


<!--  jQuery 1.7+  -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!--
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

-->

<!-- Include js plugin -->
<script src="owl.carousel.js"></script>



<script>


$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#owl-carousel, #owl-carousel2').owlCarousel({
    margin:10,
    loop:true,
    autoWidth:true,
    items:4,
    autoplay:true
    })

});



</script>                             


</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<div class="header">NEW DVDS</div>
    <asp:Literal ID="ltlBooks2" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
<div class="header2">WEEKLY STAFF PICKS</div>
    <asp:Literal ID="ltlBooks" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</div>
</form>

<div id="footer"><img src="logo.png" /></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

/////////

Update - the issues was on line 81

Dim nodes2 As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc2.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/xml/books/book")

I wasn't using xmlDoc2 after the = sign.

//////////